# Arranging red and blue tiles in a line with at least 1 blue tile between any 2 red tiles

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

BdMO 2010 Nationals:

> Tom and Jerry have $8$ blue tiles and $6$ red tiles.They want to arrange them in a straight line so that between any $2$ red tiles there is always at least $1$ blue tile.In how many ways can that be done?

Note that the question says "**any** 2 red tiles" and not "consecutive red tiles".

Number of permutations of $6$ red tiles and $8$ blue tiles $$\dbinom{14}{6}$$

A thing to note is that there can be a maximum of 3 tiles between 2 consecutive tiles if we want to fulfil the terms and conditions of the question.

However,I am at complete loss to see any strategy to attack this problem.We can divide the tiles into group such as (i)6 RB-groups and 1 RBB group(ii)6 BR-groups and 1 RBB group.If we calculate these separately,we shall still miss some cases.I am having trouble organizing all the case.Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the key idea of a solution would be to divide the problem into cases.

Comment: Are the same colour tiles identical or distinguishable?  If identical, then line up the red ones first, put a blue in between each, and all you're left is to count how to put three identical blues in seven distinct locations.

Comment: @Macavity,identical,and thanks for the solution.

Comment: so $\dbinom 7 3$?

Comment: @LeoAzevedo, I believe it should be $9 \choose 3$.

Comment: Your note ("any 2 red tiles" and not "consecutive red tiles") is irrelevant to the answer $-$ the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: @Macavity: Yes, but...you have to allow for multiple blue tiles at the same location. So it's not as simple as $\dbinom{7}{3}$.

Comment: @Tony K,yes it is completely irrelevant.I didn't put too much effort in thinking it out.

Comment: @TonyK I never said it was $\binom{7}{3}$.  You need stars and bars to finish, which gives you $\binom{9}{3}$ as Pedro points out above.

Comment: For the uninitiated: "stars and bars" is explained in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Count the automorphisms of the Fano plane :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.  Line up the eight blue tiles.  There are nine locations, seven between them and one on each end.  You need to choose six of those locations each to receive one red tile:  ${9 \choose 6}$ ways

Comment: Simpler solution. +1!